# Create batch file to copy mdb file to another folder and renaming it

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create batch file to copy mdb file to another folder then renaming it and run a task scheduler everyday. so everytime the batch runs, the same mdb file will copy and rename. I don't care about the additional characters just copy and rename will do.

folder A (source folder)

```
 test.mdb     06/21/2014
```

folder B (target folder)

```
 test02.mdb   06/21/2014
 test03.mdb   06/22/2014
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
copy "c:\folder a\test.mdb" "b:\folder b\test%random%.mdb"
```

The random number is 0 to 32,000. To do it by dates

```
Set NewDate=%date:/=%
copy "c:\folder a\test.mdb" "b:\folder b\test%newdate%.mdb"
```

Comment: It's sample code, you have to fix it to suit your circumstances. However date have forward slashes so this line has been changed. `Set NewDate=%date:/=%`

Answer (score 0):

This will copy and rename a file:

```
copy "folder A\test.mdb" "folder B\test02.mdb"
```